# How to drop values duplicated in column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have file which contain userId,MovieId,ratings. Each user should rate 30  movies.

How can I drop users who gave less than 30 ratings and movieId which have an average rating below 3 ? Ratings are between 1 and 5.

[image]

Comment: Hi Salma, you need windowing for this. You can take a look at this link if it helps : http://queirozf.com/entries/spark-dataframe-examples-window-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df
  .withColumn("averageMovieRating", avg("ratings").over(Window.partitionBy("movieid")))
  .withColumn("userRatingCount", count("userid").over(Window.partitionBy("userid")))
  .where($"userRatingCount" > 30 && $"averageMovieRating" >= 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `groupBy` and `Window` function as below and generate final `DataFrame(df2)`

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
scala> val W_movie = Window.partitionBy("movieid")

// Input DataFrame
scala> df.show
+------+-------+------+
|userid|movieid|rating|
+------+-------+------+
|     1|   2121|     1|
|     1|    223|   1.5|
|     1|     41|   2.5|
|     1|  14123|     2|
|     1|     41|   3.5|
|     1|     14|     5|
|     2|     14|     4|
|     2|     14|     5|
|     2|     14|   2.3|
|     3|   2121|     1|
|     3|    223|     3|
|     3|     41|     2|
|     3|  14123|   3.5|
|     3|     41|   1.5|
|     4|     11|     4|
|     4|     11|   4.5|
|     4|     33|     5|
|     4|  14123|     2|
+------+-------+------+

//DataFrame to get number of ratings given by every user
scala> val df1 = df.alias("in").join(df.groupBy("userid").agg(count(lit(1)).alias("userCount")).alias("count"), List("userid"))

scala> df1.show
+------+-------+------+---------+
|userid|movieid|rating|userCount|
+------+-------+------+---------+
|     1|   2121|     1|        6|
|     1|    223|   1.5|        6|
|     1|     41|   2.5|        6|
|     1|  14123|     2|        6|
|     1|     41|   3.5|        6|
|     1|     14|     5|        6|
|     2|     14|     4|        3|
|     2|     14|     5|        3|
|     2|     14|   2.3|        3|
|     3|   2121|     1|        5|
|     3|    223|     3|        5|
|     3|     41|     2|        5|
|     3|  14123|   3.5|        5|
|     3|     41|   1.5|        5|
|     4|     11|     4|        4|
|     4|     11|   4.5|        4|
|     4|     33|     5|        4|
|     4|  14123|     2|        4|
+------+-------+------+---------+

//DataFrame to get average Rating of each movieId 


scala> val df2 = df1.withColumn("AvgRating", avg(col("rating")).over(W_movie).cast("Decimal(2,1)"))

scala> df2.show
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+
|userid|movieid|rating|userCount|AvgRating|
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+
|     4|     11|     4|        4|      4.3|
|     4|     11|   4.5|        4|      4.3|
|     1|   2121|     1|        6|      1.0|
|     3|   2121|     1|        5|      1.0|
|     1|    223|   1.5|        6|      2.3|
|     3|    223|     3|        5|      2.3|
|     1|  14123|     2|        6|      2.5|
|     3|  14123|   3.5|        5|      2.5|
|     4|  14123|     2|        4|      2.5|
|     1|     41|   2.5|        6|      2.4|
|     1|     41|   3.5|        6|      2.4|
|     3|     41|     2|        5|      2.4|
|     3|     41|   1.5|        5|      2.4|
|     4|     33|     5|        4|      5.0|
|     1|     14|     5|        6|      4.1|
|     2|     14|     4|        3|      4.1|
|     2|     14|     5|        3|      4.1|
|     2|     14|   2.3|        3|      4.1|
+------+-------+------+---------+---------+
```

You can run your filter over final dataframe (df2) for your requirement.

> users who gave less than 30 ratings and movieId which have an average
>   rating below 3

```
df2.filter(col("userCount") >= 30 && col("AvgRating") >= 3).select("userid","movieid","rating")
```

Comment: thanks ,but I need average rating for each movieId and count how many movies rated by each user.